# Adding Classes to SVG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, svg, webpacker

I've replaced the Asset Pipeline with Webpacker but am looking for a neat and tidy way to insert svg files inline instead of as images.

I've written a small helper file `inline_svg_helper.rb` that I'm using, but I am worried this is super slow. Should I be?

This is what the helper looks like:

```
require 'nokogiri'
module InlineSvgHelper
  def the_inline_svg(path, css="")
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("public#{path}"))
    svg = doc.at_css "svg"
    svg['class'] = "#{css}"
    return raw doc
  end
end
```

This is how I call it: 
`<%= the_inline_svg("public#{asset_pack_path('images/grapes.svg')}", 'h-1/4 w-1/4') %>`

How would I cache something like this? What is a more efficient way to handle this?